# How to add to the custom search filter in all column fields on the following datatable

Tags: javascript, apex-code, visualforce

My controller:

```
 public class SortOfContactListController {
        public List<Contact> ContactListTable {get; set;}
        public String ExpressionOfSort = 'name';
        public String DirectionOfSort = 'ASC';

        public SortOfContactListController() {
            ContactListTable = new List<Contact>();
        }
        public String ExpressionSort {
            get {
                return ExpressionOfSort;
            }
            set {
                If(value == ExpressionOfSort) {
                    DirectionOfSort = (DirectionOfSort == 'ASC')? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
                }
                else {
                    DirectionOfSort = 'ASC';
                    ExpressionOfSort = value;
                }
            }

        }

        public String getDirectionOfSort() {
            If(ExpressionOfSort == Null || ExpressionOfSort == '') {
                return 'DESC';
            }
            else {
                return DirectionOfSort;
            }
        }

        public void setDirectionOfSort(String value) {
            DirectionOfSort = value;
        }

        public List<Contact>getContacts() {
            return ContactListTable;
        }

        public PageReference ViewData() {
            String FullSortExpression = ExpressionOfSort + ' ' + DirectionOfSort;
            system.debug('ExpressionOfSort:::::'+ExpressionOfSort);
            system.debug(DirectionOfSort);

            //String Queryitem = new String();
           String Queryitem = 'SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, Birthdate, Phone, Email, MailingCity, MailingCountry, MailingPostalCode FROM Contact WHERE Account.Name != Null ORDER BY ' + FullSortExpression + ' Limit 1000';

            ContactListTable = DataBase.query(Queryitem);
            system.debug(ContactListTable);
            return Null;
        }
    }
```

My visual page:

```
<apex:page controller="SortOfContactListController" action="{!ViewData}"  >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:sectionHeader title="ListOfContacts With Accounts"/>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ContactListTable}" var="contact" rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(ContactListTable))}" id="cmdsort">

                 <apex:column >
                     <apex:facet name="header">   
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Contact Name{!IF(ExpressionSort=='name',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC', '▼', '▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="name" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                     <apex:outputLink value="/{!contact.Id}" target="_blank">{!contact.Name}</apex:outputLink>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.Account.Name}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Account Name{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Account.Name',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="Account.Name" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.Birthdate}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Birth Date{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Birthdate',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="Birthdate" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.Phone}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Phone{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Phone',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="Phone" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.Email}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Email{!IF(ExpressionSort=='Email',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="Email" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCity}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing City{!IF(ExpressionSort=='MailingCity',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="MailingCity" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingCountry}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing Country{!IF(ExpressionSort=='MailingCountry',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="MailingCountry" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

                  <apex:column value="{!contact.MailingPostalCode}">
                     <apex:facet name="header">
                       <apex:commandLink action="{!ViewData}" value="Mailing Postal Code{!IF(ExpressionSort=='MailingPostalCode',IF(DirectionOfSort == 'ASC','▼','▲'),'')}">
                         <apex:param value="MailingPostalCode" name="column" assignTo="{!ExpressionSort}" ></apex:param>
                       </apex:commandLink>
                     </apex:facet>
                  </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>            
        </apex:pageBlock>        
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here I try to the ascending and descending order of the each column and to now. But I am try to get a search bar

For each column to fill the detail and click the button I got that appropriate data on the table.

So that is I don't know to the how to gwet it please help me.

Here for your help each column to be passed through to the way of the variable key word of name that is updating to the dynamic query to the page to the controller to produce the ascending and descending order so my required is to be also to when they answered to be minded on the dynamic query manner the answer please.